# Import-CSV cares that I have duplicate members, but I need the duplicates

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm writing a simple powershell script to open a CSV which is generated by me and push each element into a telnet session to provision devices. However, my script won't even start due to the fact that I have duplicate members! If anyone has guidance on this please let me know.

This is the powershell, I'm not well versed in it, I was just using old code to test this would work.

```
$CSVFile = Import-CSV "C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\AMSProvisioning\code.CSV"

foreach ($Line in $CSVFile){
    $GroupArray = $Line.split(",")
    foreach ($code in $GroupArray){
        "$code has been created!"
    }
}
```

This is the CSV file. It is just a list of commands that would normally be hand typed into a switch to configure/provision devices. This is a test CSV file as well.

```
configure Equipment ont interface 1/1/1/3/1 sw-ver-plannd UNPLANNED sernum ALCL:7788h67a,"configure Equipment ont interface 1/1/1/3/1 desc1 ""Alex Manley""","configure Equipment ont interface 1/1/1/3/1 desc2 ""185 Alexander St""",configure equipment ont interface 1/1/1/3/1 admin-state down,configure equipment ont slot 1/1/1/3/1/1 planned-card-type 10_100base plndnumdataports 4 plndnumvoiceports 0 admin-state up,configure ethernet ont 1/1/1/3/1/1/[1...4] auto-detect auto,configure interface port uni:1/1/1/3/1/1/[1...4] admin-up,exit all,configure qos interface 1/1/1/3/1/1/[1...4] upstream-queue 0 bandwidth-profile name:BE_20Mb bandwidth-sharing uni-sharing,configure qos interface 1/1/1/3/1/1/[1...4] queue 0 shaper-profile name:100Mb_DOWN,configure bridge port 1/1/1/3/1/1/[1...4] max-unicast-mac 8,configure bridge port 1/1/1/3/1/1/[1...4] vlan-id 134 tag untagged,configure bridge port 1/1/1/3/1/1/[1...4] pvid 134 default-priority 0,configure interface port uni:1/1/1/3/1/1/[1...4] admin-up,exit all,configure equipment ont interface 1/1/1/3/1 admin-state up
```

Comment: It's not going to work as long as you have duplicate members, so the solution is going to have to work around that.  It would help if you explain why you need the duplicates.

Comment: The CSV is actually a bit of code I need to run on a switch, the devices will not work correctly if the duplicate is not there. I've also added the two test files I'm using so everyone may see what I mean.

Comment: could you please format the csv sample so we can see where one line ends and the next starts? @mjolinor what makes you think that? i can import csvs with duplicate members just fine

Comment: @paul Depends what he means by members. Column names could conflict. Either way a sample is needed

Comment: @Paul, it looks like there is just one line with all the commands in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Importing-CSV I've switched to using get-content, as it pretty much performs the same function I need. Sorry bug you all, but thanks much for your help!

Comment: I undeleted this as i answered my own post and don't want people to continually waste their time by trying to answer this when I found a work around. If you want it in answerform I can do that, but c'mon mods pay attention to who the poster is.

Comment: If you dont want people wasting their time then this question should just be deleted. This question and answer combination does not help the community at all. Yes you answered your own question but not in a way that _clearly_ helps anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, that is not really a CSV in the sense that it does not have a header. You don't really want it to be a CSV to be honest, you just want it to be a series of commands. Instead of Import-CSV what you want to use is Get-Content. That won't create an object with properties, but you can split the string on commas and get an array that you can process. Something like:

```
$commands = Get-Content 'C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\AMSProvisioning\code.CSV' |
    ForEach-Object{$_.Split(',')}
```

That first part imports the CSV as an array of strings. Then for each line it splits that line on the comma creating  an array of individual commands. All of the commands are assigned to $code.

If you need each line to be it's own set of code, and have an array of sets of code you could turn each line into an object, and have each object have one property that is an array of that line split on the comma. Something like:

```
$commands = Get-Content 'C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\AMSProvisioning\code.CSV' |
    ForEach{New-Object PSObject -Prop @{'Code'=$_.split(',')}}
```

That way $commands[0].code (the first record of $commands) will be an array of commands derived from the first line of the CSV file. I don't remember how to make an array of arrays, which would probably be ideal for you, but this should work quite well.

Comment: If this answer is correct, Alex should flag it as correct.  This will help the community, and future visitors.